# Web app can't read it's own DOM elements when in an iframe. Works fine outside of iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a heavily customized web app (made with Gradio) that needs to go into an iframe on another site.

Website is hosted on Digital Ocean. Gradio app is hosted on a local PC. Gradio app is js/css/html.

When I load the Gradio app directly in the browser, everything works as expected.

If I put the app in an iframe (otherwise skeleton HTML/not other scripts loaded) it seems as though the Gradio app can no longer read it's own DOM elements via it's own js.

```
<iframe src="https://12894.gradio.app" name="frame2" id="frame2" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementById')" and such.

I'm NOT trying to read or change elements inside the iframe with anything outside of the iframe or vice/versa.

My understanding was that when loading a page in an iframe, it should be able to read/modify it's own elements with it's own scripts. Am I mistaken?

Comment: What do you see in the Console tab of your browser devtools? And, maybe in the Network tab? Sometimes you'll see messages that tell you exactly what's wrong. You can [edit] your question to show us that info if you need help making sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, Gradio uses a shadow DOM that confuses things. Just removed it from their code. Runs fine now.

```
function gradioApp(){
return document.getElementsByTagName('gradio-app')[0].shadowRoot;}
```

to

```
function gradioApp(){
return document;}
```

In case anyone else runs into this.
Thanks for everyone's quick help!

Comment: Or use for example `$("table span", document.getElementsByTagName('gradio-app')[0].shadowRoot)` instead of `$("table span")`